# Splunk AWS ALB logs not properly parsing

Tags: amazon-elb, splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to ingest my **AWS ALB** logs into **Splunk**. After all, I could search my ALB logs in Splunk. But still the events are not properly parsing. Did anyone had similar issue or any suggestion?

Here is my **prop.conf**

```html
[aws:alb:accesslogs]
SHOULD_LINEMERGE=false
FIELD_DELIMITER = whitespace
pulldown_type=true
FIELD_NAMES=type,timestamp,elb,client_ip,client_port,target,request_processing_time,target_processing_time,response_processing_time,elb_status_code,target_status_code,received_bytes,sent_bytes,request,user_agent,ssl_cipher,ssl_protocol,target_group_arn,trace_id
EXTRACT-elb = ^\s*(?P<type>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<timestamp>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<elb>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<client_ip>[0-9.]+):(?P<client_port>\d+)\s+(?P<target>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<request_processing_time>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<target_processing_time>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<response_processing_time>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<elb_status_code>[\d-]+)\s+(?P<target_status_code>[\d-]+)\s+(?P<received_bytes>\d+)\s+(?P<sent_bytes>\d+)\s+"(?P<request>.+)"\s+"(?P<user_agent>.+)"\s+(?P<ssl_cipher>[-\w]+)\s*(?P<ssl_protocol>[-\w\.]+)\s+(?P<target_group_arn>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<trace_id>[^\s]+)
EVAL-rtt = request_processing_time + target_processing_time + response_processing_time
```

**Sample data**

```html
https 2020-08-20T12:40:00.274478Z app/my-aws-alb/e7538073dd1a6fd8 162.158.26.188:21098 172.0.51.37:80 0.000 0.004 0.000 405 405 974 424 "POST https://my-aws-alb-domain:443/api/ps/fpx/callback HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.2840.91 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-1:111111111111:targetgroup/my-aws-target-group/41dbd234b301e3d84 "Root=1-5f3e6f20-3fdasdsfffdsf" "api.mydomain.com" "arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-1:11111111111:certificate/be4344424-a40f-416e-8434c-88a8a3b072f5" 0 2020-08-20T12:40:00.270000Z "forward" "-" "-" "172.0.51.37:80" "405" "-" "-"
```

Comment: Please share some sample data so we can compare it to your props.conf settings.  Also, which events are not extracted properly?

Comment: Thanks for the response @RichG. Here I have attached the sample logs in original question.

Comment: Basically nothing is parsing properly. It just show the same logs when searched. Only the host, source, sourcetype and splunk_server fields get extracted.

Comment: That EXTRACT expression works in regex101.com so I'm surprised it's not working in Splunk.  Did you install the props.conf file on the search head and restart Splunk?

Comment: Should I do it in search head cluster as well? Usually, I do in HF and IDX nodes (through Master indexer) only.

Comment: Since `EXTRACT` is a search-time setting, the props.conf file must be installed on your SHs.  If you need index-time extractions then use `TRANSFORMS` on the HFs and indexers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Could you please help me how to do `TRANSFORMS` for this particular thing?. I'm very new to the Splunk and wouldn't have much idea on this.

Comment: I did the exactly same way you have mentioned in the Answer. But still no luck. Let me check if I made other mistakes and keep you posted. Meanwhile, please advice if you see any changes to be done. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi @RichG, Would like to check with you, is there any other advice you could give? Still my issue was not resolved : (

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220209/discussion-between-richg-and-hlesnt395).

Answer (score 2):

Using transforms is pretty straightforward.  Start with a stanza in transforms.conf.

```
[elb]
REGEX = ^\s*(?P<type>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<timestamp>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<elb>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<client_ip>[0-9.]+):(?P<client_port>\d+)\s+(?P<target>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<request_processing_time>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<target_processing_time>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<response_processing_time>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<elb_status_code>[\d-]+)\s+(?P<target_status_code>[\d-]+)\s+(?P<received_bytes>\d+)\s+(?P<sent_bytes>\d+)\s+"(?P<request>.+)"\s+"(?P<user_agent>.+)"\s+(?P<ssl_cipher>[-\w]+)\s*(?P<ssl_protocol>[-\w\.]+)\s+(?P<target_group_arn>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<trace_id>[^\s]+)
```

Then refer to the transform in props.conf

```
[aws:alb:accesslogs]
TIME_PREFIX = https\s
TIME_FORMAT = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%Z
MAX_TIMESTAMP_LOOKAHEAD = 32
SHOULD_LINEMERGE=false
NO_BINARY_CHECK=true
TRANSFORMS-elb = elb
EVAL-rtt = request_processing_time + target_processing_time + response_processing_time
```